# DataGrid with dynamic columns, how to customize cell background using databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have the following simplified structures:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ResultModel> results;
    public class ResultModel {
        public string FileName{get; set;}
        public ObservableCollection<TableModel>{get;set;}
    }
    public class TableModel {
        public string TableName{get; set;}
        public DataTable Table{get; set;}
    }
    public class HighlightedValue {
        public string Value{get; set;}
        public Brush Background{get; set;}
    }
```

Depending on the number of files, I might have several ResultModels. I want to present this information as DataGrids, so what I did was use ItemsControl to bind to both Collections and finally inside the DataTemplate I have bound the  DataGrid's ItemSource to each of the DataTable's DefaultViews.

This works great, but there is an added problem, I need to change the background color of the cells, ideally every cell should be composed of some text and a background, bound to HighLightedValue's respective values. However I can't seem to find a way to achieve this.

I don't necessarily need to represent the Tables as DataTables if there is a more convenient way.

How do I bind every cell's value in every column's background and text?

Answer (score 0):

It's not binding but you might be able to get away with creating your own custom columns with logic to set the background color and replace the ones that are auto generated.

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" AutoGeneratedColumns="grid_AutoGeneratedColumns" />
```

Code behind:

```
private void grid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var columnsToReplace = new List<DataGridTextColumn>();

            foreach (var col in this.grid.Columns)
            {
                var textCol = col as DataGridTextColumn;
                if (textCol != null)
                {
                    columnsToReplace.Add(textCol);                  
                }
            }

            foreach(var col in columnsToReplace)
            {
                this.ReplaceColumn(col, CopyColumn(col));
            }
        }


        private void ReplaceColumn(DataGridBoundColumn originalColumn, DataGridBoundColumn newColumn)
        {
            this.grid.Columns.Add(newColumn);

            this.grid.Columns.Remove(originalColumn);
        }
        private DataGridTextColumn CopyColumn(DataGridTextColumn originalColumn)
        {
            var newCol = new DataGridTextColumnEx();

            newCol.Binding = originalColumn.Binding;
            newCol.Header = originalColumn.Header;

            return newCol;
        }
```

Custom column:

```
class DataGridTextColumnEx : DataGridTextColumn
        {
            protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
            {
                var textBlock = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem) as TextBlock;

                //Probably use dataItem to set color
                textBlock.Background = Brushes.Red;

                return textBlock;
            }

            protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
            {
                var textBox = base.GenerateEditingElement(cell, dataItem) as TextBox;

                //Probably use dataItem to set color
                textBox.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                return textBox;
            }
        }
```

In the GenerateElement methods you can probably setup binding in the code if you wanted to. I think the dataItem is the object you will want to bind to.

Comment: Right, but I don't have a single DataGrid, I have a variable number of datagrids. The big problem here is, the value of the background depends on the HighLightedValue object, so ideally I would bind textbox.Background to the Background property and the textbox.Text property to Value.